# Stuck Form multithreading without WPF

Tags: forms, powershell

I can create a form and I can modify my richtextbox. But my form is stuck and I can't move this form. I would like to know how a can start my form and run script inside. When i use a start-job my richtextbox is not modify :/ 
I heard about multithreading but when i look example its only for WPF form :/

Do you have an idea ?

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

function Clean {


do{
start-sleep 1
$richtextbox1.AppendText("------------STEP 1-----------`n")
} While ($i = "45")



}


function CreateForm {

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.drawing

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

#Form Parameter
$form1.Text = "Clean"
$form1.Name = "Clean"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 600
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 500
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$Form1.MinimizeBox = $True
$Form1.MaximizeBox = $True
$form1.ControlBox = $True
$form1.Topmost = $False
$Form1.AutoSize = $True
$Form1.ShowInTaskbar = $True
$form1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,40) 
$label1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,40) 
$label1.Text = "CLEAN"
$label1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",18,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
$form1.Controls.Add($label1) 

$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,125) 
$label2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,40) 
$label2.Text = "Step : "
$label2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
$form1.Controls.Add($label2)

$label3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,175) 
$label3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,40) 
$label3.Text = ""
$label3.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8)
$form1.Controls.Add($label3)


$richTextBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$richTextBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,250) 
$richTextBox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,200) 
$richTextBox1.Text = "`n"
$richTextBox1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif",8,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::bold)
$form1.Controls.Add($richTextBox1)



$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Show the Form

$form1.add_Shown({ Clean })
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

}

CreateForm
```

Regards

Comment: Did you check this link? https://www.sapien.com/blog/2012/05/16/powershell-studio-creating-responsive-forms/

Comment: The Multi-Threading stuff you saw for WPF GUI's *should* work essentially the same way using WinForms, basically, you need to run your form in one thread and then have it spawn additional threads to do actual work, if you want data from your worker threads to update the GUI you'll need to use synced hash tables, otherwise your GUI has no access to the data generated by the worker threads.  some good examples here - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/08/14/lessons-learned-while-writing-the-powershell-poshpaig-module/